# setAttribute isn't doing anything

Tags: php, html, dom

I have a PHP page. It is supposed to to get all of hrefs of links in the page and change them to something else, and then show the page. But it isn't doing that. Here is my code:

```
$returndata = file_get_contents($url);
$doc= new DOMDocument(); 
@$doc->loadHTML($returndata);
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $anchor)
{
        $href=$anchor->getAttribute('href');
        $splited=str_split($href);
        $hashed=implode("*",$splited);
        $anchor->setAttribute("href", $hashed);
} 
echo $returndata;
```

but the `setAttribute` isn't doing anything. Then I tried adding this before that:

```
$anchor->removeAttribute("href");
```

but there is no change.

Comment: So, you are changing properties of an `object` and try to see them in `a string`?

Comment: Relevant documentation: [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), [`DOMElement`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php), [`DOMElement::setAttribute`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php)

Comment: echoing `$returndata` has nothing to do with the HTML document you are processing. It's the old, unchanged string data. You need to output the `DOMDocument`

Comment: More relevant documentation: [`DOMDocument::saveHTML`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php)

Comment: @Pekka thanks alot! i changed it to `echo $doc->saveHTML();` and everything is ok now !

Comment: You're welcome. I'll add it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echoing `$returndata` in your example has nothing to do with the HTML document you are processing. It's the old, unchanged string data.

You need to output the actual `DOMDocument` you're manipulating using [`DomDocument::saveHTML`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php).